# New SSH key in cloudbees

Tags: openssh, cloudbees

I'm creating a new SSH key with my account in Cloudbees. In public key box, i gave

`ssh-rsa <key> user@publicIP.com`

but this shows **"could not be fingerprinted"**. I'm new to Cloudbees, can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that your SSH key is invalid.

You can test your key using

```
cat > file.pub <<EOF
ssh-rsa <key> user@publicIP.com
EOF
ssh-keygen -l -f file.pub
```